# how to optimize multiprocessing in this code?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Results is a very big variable and I will do:

```
results = sum(results, [])
print 'Writing results json to %s' % res_file
with open(res_file, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(results, f, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

for it. But how to store the big variable in generate process?

```
pool = mp.Pool(8)
results = pool.map(coco_results_one_category_kernel, data_pack)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

This code will cannot allocation memory for the multiprocessing:

> OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory

```
results = []
for i in range(len(data_pack)):
     print i,'/',len(data_pack)
     results.append(coco_results_one_category_kernel(data_pack[i]))
results = sum(results, [])
```

This code will be killed when `i=36` because of result is too big. How can I do for this? I do not care the time, just get the result variable.

Comment: What system do you use? On Windows every new process is a clone of the parent, hence you multiply the required memory. It would be necessary to share the data between the processes or split it into chunks first.